# How do you batch SELECT statements when you can't rely on the IDs to be in literal order?

Tags: mysql, sql

*What I mean by literal order is that, altough the IDs are auto-increment, through business logic, it might end up that 8 comes after 4 when 5 should've been there. That is to say, if a deletion if ID happens, there's no re-indexing*

This is how my rows look (table name is wp_posts):

```
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| ID  | post_author | .. |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| 4   | ..          |    |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| 8   | ..          |    |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| 124 | ..          |    |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| 672 | ..          |    |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| 673 | ..          |    |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
| 674 | ..          |    |  |  |  |
+-----+-------------+----+--+--+--+
```

ID is an `int` that has the `auto-increment` characteristic, **but** when a post is deleted, there is no re-assignment of IDs. It will just simply get deleted and because it's auto-increment, you can still assume that, vertically, the items that come after the one you're looking at are always bigger than the ones before.

I'm querying for ID: `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts` to get a list of all the IDs I need. Now, it just so happens that I need to batch all of this, using AJAX requests because once I retrieve the IDs, I need to operate on them.

Thing is, I don't really understand how to pass my data back to AJAX. What `LIMIT` does is, if I provide 2 arguments, such as: `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts LIMIT 1,3`, it'll return back `4,8,124` because it looks at **row number**. But what do I do on the next call? Yes, the first call always starts with `1`, but once I need to launch the second AJAX request to perform yet another `SELECT`, how do I know where I should start? In my case, I'd want to start again at `4`, so, my second query would be `SELECT ID FROM wp_posts LIMIT 4, 7` and so on.

Do I really need to send that counter (even if I can automate it, since, you see, it's an increment of `3`) back?

Is there no way for SQL to handle this automatically?

Comment: As far as I could understand, you want to return the first three rows of your query ordered by currently existing ID values, don't you ?

Answer (score 1):

You have many confusions in your question.  Let me try to clear up some basic ones.

First, the auto-incremented key is the primary key for the table.  You do not need to worry about gaps.  In fact, the key should basically be meaningless.  It fulfills the following:

- It is guaranteed to be unique.
- It is guaranteed to be in insertion order.

Gaps are allowed and of no concern.  There is no re-indexing.  It is a bad idea because:

- Primary keys uniquely identify each row and this mapping should be consistent across time.
- Primary keys are used in other tables to refer to values, so re-indexing would either invalidate those relationships or require massive changes to many tables.
- Re-indexes pre-supposes that the value means something, when it doesn't.

Second, a query such as:

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_posts
LIMIT 1, 3;
```

Can return *any* three rows.  Why?  Because you have no specified an `ORDER BY` and SQL result sets without `ORDER BY` are *unordered*.  There are no guarantees.  So you  should always be in the habit of using an `ORDER BY`.

Third, if you want to essentially "page" through results, then use the `OFFSET` feature in `LIMIT` (as you have above):

```
SELECT ID
FROM wp_posts
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT @offset, 3;
```

This will allow you to reset the `@offset` value and go to which rows you want.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the clarifications. A lot. As for my AJAX-based "count", do I still have to set what my last offset is and make the new (next) query starting with that last offset?

Comment: @coolpasta . . . You do not have to, but that is often the case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you want to return the first three rows of your query ordered by currently existing ID values(whatever they're after all DML statement's applied on the table `wp_posts`).

Then, Consider using an auxiliary iteration variable `@i` to provide an ordered integer value set starting from `1` and increasing as `2`,`3`,... without any gaps :

```
select t.*
  from 
  ( 
   select @i :=  @i + 1 as rownum, t1.*
     from tab t1
     join (select @i:=0) t2
  ) t 
 order by rownum 
 limit 0,3;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=155cbbf961bea7bb692916ba9d749fa4)</kbd>

Comment: I call upon all the holy power that exists in this world to aid me in defeating the devil. What is this? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @coolpasta you need a fake column `@i` in the subquery, and aliased as `rownum` in the main query to provide the iteration.

Comment: Although if you're using a current version of MySQL (by no means a given), you can eschew the temporary variable `@i`, and use the [ROW_NUMBER window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/window-function-descriptions.html).

Comment: Yes,I know @Zack , but those window analytic functions work for version 8+ only.As long as OP don't tag the version8,we're looking for a generic solution.

Comment: I don't see what all this is suppose to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

First query:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts ORDER BY ID LIMIT 3
```

This returns 4,8,124 as you said. In your client, *save the largest ID value in a variable*.

Subsequent queries:

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE ID > ? ORDER BY ID LIMIT 3
```

Send a parameter into this query using the greated ID value from the previous result. It's still in a variable.

This also helps make the query faster, because it doesn't have to skip all those initial rows every time. Paging through a large dataset using LIMIT/OFFSET is pretty inefficient. SQL has to actually read all those rows even though it's not going to return them.

But if you use `WHERE ID > ?` then SQL can efficiently start the scan in the right place, on the first row that would be included in the result.